# Setting up PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

never mind, needed to do pip install --update pymongo

I'm following this page - http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

When I put in

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 284, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Python.tmbundle/Support/sitecustomize.py", line 44, in tm_excepthook
    io = fdopen(error_fd, 'wb', 0)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 284, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: can you add other part of your code ?

Comment: thats all the code I have. It breaks when I do the import

Comment: my code is 1 line - from pymongo import MongoClient and that breaks it

Answer (score 0):

It was actually due to an old version of pymongo. pip install --update pymongo fixed it